# Height of weight dropped vs launch distance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

Say you have a system where a weight drops on an air source, which blows on the ball, launching it. Are there any relations or formulas between the forces at work here? For instance, would there be an exponential relation between the distance the ball travels vs the height of the weight? Or would there be a relation between the angle the ball is launched at vs the height of the weight? Since there are so many forces at work here, any relation between one variable and another would be helpful.

Comment: You would need to model air resistance, perhaps you could use a linear or quadratic model in the velocity, or you could make use of one of the ballistics "G" models.